# Is it possible to configure a Node.js http module to support %20?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server

Just a quick question before I start renaming several hundred image files ...

To get around CORS restrictions, my Electron app runs a Node js server, so that I can convert local image files to dataURLs on the fly.

However, many of my image files have spaces in their names, which throw "not found" errors, even if the spaces are replaced by "%20".

To make sure that this is a server, rather than coding error, I manually typed (e.g.): http://localhost:9000/images/vocab/food/ice%20cream.jpg into the browser address bar and the server returns "not found".

Does anyone know of a way to configure the Node.js http module to support this standard?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url) (and in particular, the part about parsing the request-URL)?

Comment: Thanks for the lead Robert. I looked into it and in fact resolve-url looks more promising - parse-url seems to be mostly about parsing urls with variables. 
For the moment, I've decided to rename the images. I knew spaces in filenames was poor programming practice - now I know why!!!